# Send SMS within Expo app without redirecting to the device default messaging app

Tags: react-native, expo, sms

As part of a school project I am working on, I am trying to build a messaging app that utilizes SMS as the default method for sending and receiving SMS without redirecting to the default SMS Messaging App of the device (ie sending/receiving an SMS for my app without redirecting to the Messages app on the iPhone). but I haven't found anything that can be used to achieve this.

PS: One of the requirements of the projects is not using any external library, except for the things provided with Expo,

Comment: Since this feature is not built into react-native, my guess is that you will need to implement a native module yourself in android and ios.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use an external library. That feature isnt build in react Native

One external Library would be "https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sms"

The only option you have if you really dont want to use external librarys is, to write your own function, which communicates with the native API